# Log is not working inside the java file. But works inside the servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, apache-axis

I have issue in executing the logs. I have two projects: one is a servlet and the other one is a simple java file. `private static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(myServiceServlet.class);` This was working fine. Its writing log wen i start running the Tomcat server. But the same thing is not achieve in my simple java file, it converted into WS and try to deploy in axis/Tomcat server
Servlet is directly running in Tomcat server.
But java file is converted into Webservice.aar inside the Axis2--->Tomcat server.

Log Properites

```
# Log levels
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,CONSOLE,R

# Appender Configuration
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

# Rolling File Appender
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

# Path and file name to store the log file
log4j.appender.R.File=C:/res backup/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/webapps/mylog/logs/servicelog.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=2048KB

# Number of backup files
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=50

# Layout for Rolling File Appender
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - %c - %p - %m%n`
```

Comment: Can you share your logging configuration?  Where are you expecting the output?

Comment: any warnings you are getting related with logger. looks like logger is not properly initialized.

Comment: @rbhwasar ... There is no Error. it just Writing the Servlet log files inside the logger but not WS file...

Comment: @David I cant post my log file due to some security issues.. Still im confused everything is working fine. why its not writing for WS file.

Comment: Your logging configuration, not your log.

Comment: check my post i shared log properties file

Comment: What is this tagged java.util.logging if you're using log4j?

Comment: What level are you logging at?

Comment: @David  sry David im using log4j.. static Level INFO is my lvl of logging..

Answer (score 0):

The .aar files are not running in the same context as the JARs in WEB-INF/lib.

They share some kind of context as you can load references to the WEB-INF/lib classes, however its not 100% consistent at this point.

I would recommend you build some kind of wrapper in your .aar files that do nothing else then forwarding the calls into methods of JAR files that are situated in WEB-INF/lib.

You just need to make sure you load the reference from the .aar to the methods in WEB-INF/lib context correctly.

To throw errors in the .aar classes I would recommend you catch them and then throw an "AxisFault".

```
throw new AxisFault(err.getMessage());
```

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/AxisFault.html

That way we have have been able to solve almost all our issue with the context of .aar files.

Sebastian